# How to extract Head Word from a sentence in Natural Language Processing? Is there any way to get it using NLTK toolkit in python?

Tags: python-2.7

For example: "Workers dumped sacks into a bin" is a sentence and Head word of it is "dumped"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500176/how-can-i-determine-the-head-word-in-a-sentence-using-nlp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i determine the head word in a Sentence, using NLP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500176/how-can-i-determine-the-head-word-in-a-sentence-using-nlp)